# Setting up ivy local repository in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ivy

I am having a little trouble setting up my ivy local repository in my eclipse workspace.

I have created the local repository in my ivysettings.

```
<property name="ivy.local.repo.dir" value="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/local" override="false"/>

<resolvers>
... 
<filesystem name="local" changingPattern="${changing.pattern}">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.local.repo.dir}/${local.ivy.pattern}" />
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.repo.dir}/${local.artifact.pattern}" />
        </filesystem>

...

</resolvers>
```

I have IvyDE installed on my eclipse which creates an "ivy.xml" folder (similar to referenced libraries). If I want to create a local repository directory do I need to create the "local" folder within "ivy.xml" directory and put my jars in there?

I don't quite understand where I can put my private jars in my eclipse workspace so ivy can resolve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filesystem resolver is very flexible.

I normally use it as follows, the "myrepo" directory is found relative to the location of the ivysettings file:

```
<filesystem name="myrepo1">
    <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/myrepo/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
    <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/myrepo/[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
</filesystem>
```

In this second example the "myrepo" directory is relative to the ivy file:

```
<filesystem name="myrepo2">
    <ivy pattern="${ivy.basedir}/myrepo/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
    <artifact pattern="${ivy.basedir}/myrepo/[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
</filesystem>
```

Notes:

- I like this explicit approach of naming the relative location of the directory used to host the repo. Relying on the ivy defaults can be confusing.
- Same point for the file patterns. Demonstrates how flexible ivy is for hosting artifacts.
- Using the first approach is more flexible because you can use the [settings](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/settings.html) task within your build to specify an alternative location for the ivysettings file.

Comment: so in the myrepo folder you have a folder [organisation] and within that a [module] folder "ivy-[revision].xml" I think my folder structure might be wrong

Comment: ok I have nearly got it working. I had to set the ReturnFirst property to true. It seems to want to pick up the jar but I get a "configuration not found" error. Its looking for runtime conf.

Comment: @Decrypter If it's complaining about a configuration then sounds like an issue with a module ivy file or configuration mapping. Not the resolver.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need to put an ivy.xml in the local folder aswell which contain the dependency information?

Comment: @Decrypter That would be my assumption.... The normal convention is to have an "ivy.xml" file in the root directory of your project. It's purpose is to list your project's 3rd party dependencies. The purpose of an ivysettings file is to tell ivy where and how to retrieve those dependencies. The settings file is in fact optional (in which case ivy will retrieve from Maven Central) but it's a good idea to include it, especially as in your case you're retrieving files from a non-standard location.